# Can I have a method that returns a generic, of type generic? <T exends ...<U>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

My question is exactly what my title says.

I have the following classes

```
 public class StoreItem
 {
     //Lots of irrelevant information! :)
 }

 public class Store<T extends StoreItem>
 {
    private ArrayList<T> storeItems;
    //Other irrelevant information.
 }

 public abstract class StoreLoader<T extends StoreItem, S extends Store<T>> 
 {
     //Parsed xml document info obtained from file in constructor
     public StoreLoader (File toLoadFrom)
     {

     }

     //Here is where my question begins. I would like to do the following which states the method will return the same generic S that extends Story<of generic type T that extends storyitem>. I want to use the same T and S generics from the class definition above.
     public S<T> load ()
     {
         Store<T> store = new Store<T>(.....);
         //COde to read and process Store XML file
         return store;
     }
 }
```

EDIT: I have since removed the S generic, and made the class final. I would still like to see if something of this sort is possible though!

Comment: Try `public abstract class StoreLoader<T extends StoreItem, S extends Store<T>>`

Comment: @Eran, as you were typing that, I actually edited my answer to that exact change. I think my original question may be impossible because for it to work, you would have to initialize a generic, which can't be done. (Effectively).

Comment: You can allocate a new `Store` without its template argument, and then cast it to the proper type. This is allowed as type checking for generics is done compile time. From the bytecode perspective, all `Store`s are of type `Store<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

In your StoreLoader class definition, S is already restricted to type store (of the specific T which you created the instance with), so when you write 'S' in the function return type, you don't need to specify T again.